# Where does the following usage of worry come from?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

One of the connotations of ***[worry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/worry)***  appears to be quite different from its more common usage : *to be or cause to be anxious or uneasy, bother.*

Worry:

> (transitive)
>   to touch or poke repeatedly and idly, touch or rub constantly as in
>
> "*The old man worried his beads"*

[[Vocabulary.com/dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/worry)]

The above sense  appears to suggest a sense of relaxation rather than uneasiness.

I could not  find any reference to the above usage in [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/worry#etymonline_v_10851).

Comment: 'Worry beads' almost certainly uses this sense.

Comment: I'll note that "worry" is, somewhat archaically, used in the sense of rubbing/chipping/grinding something to change it's shape.  One might read something like "He worried a hole in the board with his pocket knife."

Answer (score 2):

Worry [LEXICO (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/worry)

> 2. with object (of a dog or other carnivorous animal) tear at, gnaw on, or drag around with the teeth.
>
>    > ‘I found my dog contentedly worrying a bone’
>
> 2.1(of a dog) chase and attack (livestock, especially sheep)
>
> > ‘a farmer shot a dog that had been worrying sheep’
>
> 2.2worry atno object Pull at or fiddle with repeatedly.
>
> > ‘he began to worry at the knot in the cord’

Etymology [LEXICO (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/worry)

> Old English wyrgan ‘strangle’, of West Germanic origin. In Middle English the original sense of the verb gave rise to the meaning ‘seize by the throat and tear’, later figuratively ‘harass’, whence ‘cause anxiety to’ (early 19th century, the date also of the noun).

In concern to "he worried his beads", he's exhibiting a sign of anxiety by fiddling with the beads, as fiddling with the beads would be an attempt to help himself relax.

*EDIT*
If you're referring to how "worry" changed from "strangle" to meaning anxious, then according to [Quword](https://www.quword.com/etym/s/worry):

> The oldest sense was obsolete in English after c. 1600; meaning "annoy, bother, vex," first recorded 1670s, developed from that of "harass by rough or severe treatment" (1550s), as of dogs or wolves attacking sheep. Meaning "to cause mental distress or trouble" is attested from 1822; intransitive sense of "to feel anxiety or mental trouble" is first recorded 1860.

However, I have not come across anything which states how it changed from "strangle" to "the feeling of anxiety".

Comment: Thanks, but the source you are citing is not the OED but Lexico.com.

Comment: Thanks! The Google page cited the source as OED. I've changed naming accordingly.

Comment: So where does the usage come from? Your source  says it is a “later figurative usage of causing harassment” which is not the case in question.

Comment: To which usage are you referring, because in your question, you're asking about "He worried his beads" which would then link to the physical action of fiddling and plucking, similar to the motion of an animal savaging its prey, which was the original meaning of the word.

Comment: More on its etymology [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worry#English).

Comment: @Gio *Lexico* is just the name of the site. The *content* comes from Oxford, just as it says on the main page: *Powered by OXFORD*.

Comment: @ChristinaHall I edited your answer to make it clearer that the actual source of the content is still Oxford. Incidentally, in making the edit I learned the trick of how to automatically hyperlink all instances of a keyword, something that I hadn't been aware of in the two years I've been on this site. The way you did that was very cool indeed, and something I might incorporate into some of my future answers.

Comment: @Jason Bassford - I don’t think lexico.com has munch in common in terms of content with the OED despite their common editor.

Comment: @Gio I didn't say the *OED*. I said *Oxford*. What's now Lexico is part of [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Dictionaries). Go to that link for detailed information.

Comment: @Jason Bassford - I am quite aware of that. My initial comment referred to the fact that the user initially cited the OED as the source for this answer.

Comment: @Gio You are aware, I hope, that Oxford Dictionaries (as represented by Lexico) is a *subset* of the OED? Things that appear in the OED don't all appear in Oxford Dictionaries. But things that appear in Oxford Dictionaries *do* appear in the OED. The *original* source of the related information still comes from the OED (at least in parallel with the overall organization).

Comment: Whatever the case, the source was misquoted. That’s it.

Answer (score 1):

To worry someone or something is when you don´t let them be. It´s like the beads have got a feeling of their own; thus would like to be at ease, but the man won´t give them even that chance as he was probably having a sweet sensation caresing them. We can say it´s a poetic sentence, it´s just to give the impression that the man´s hands were restless.